# springboot+hikaricp encounters Communications link failure

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hikaricp

The following error occurred while using Spring Boot with HikariCP to manage the MySQL connection pool:

```
2023-08-04 10:43:16.569 [xhx3-pool connection adder] ERROR c.z.h.p.HikariPool  498 createPoolEntry - xhx3-pool - Error thrown while acquiring connection from data source
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
 
The last packet successfully received from the server was 5,008 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 5,008 milliseconds ago.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.isReadOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:1419) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.isReadOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:1404) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.setupConnection(PoolBase.java:408) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.access$100(HikariPool.java:71) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:726) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:712) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
 
The last packet successfully received from the server was 5,008 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 5,008 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readMessage(NativeProtocol.java:546) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.checkErrorMessage(NativeProtocol.java:710) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendCommand(NativeProtocol.java:649) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendCommand(NativeProtocol.java:136) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.sendCommand(NativeSession.java:311) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.queryServerVariable(NativeSession.java:1008) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.isReadOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:1411) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:107) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:150) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:180) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.FullReadInputStream.readFully(FullReadInputStream.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:45) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TimeTrackingPacketReader.readHeader(TimeTrackingPacketReader.java:52) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TimeTrackingPacketReader.readHeader(TimeTrackingPacketReader.java:41) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MultiPacketReader.readHeader(MultiPacketReader.java:54) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MultiPacketReader.readHeader(MultiPacketReader.java:44) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readMessage(NativeProtocol.java:540) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.checkErrorMessage(NativeProtocol.java:710) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendCommand(NativeProtocol.java:649) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendCommand(NativeProtocol.java:136) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.sendCommand(NativeSession.java:311) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.queryServerVariable(NativeSession.java:1008) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.isReadOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:1411) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
    ... 12 more
```

My JAR package version is:
`JDK：1.8 springboot：2.5.13 hikaricp:4.0.3 mysql-connector-java：8.0.25 mysql：8.0.25-15`

The configuration of the Spring Boot service is as follows:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: XXXX
  datasource:
    xhx3:
      url: jdbc:mysql://XXX:XXXX/ledger3_lns?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true&characterEncoding=utf8
      username: XXXX
      password: XXXX
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
      type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
      hikari:
        pool-name: xhx3-pool
        minimum-idle: 30
        maximum-pool-size: 30
        idle-timeout: 360000
        keepalive-time: 60000
        max-lifetime: 540000
        connection-timeout: 30000
        auto-commit: true
        read-only: true
```

The configuration of the wait_timeout for the MySQL service is as follows:

```
+-------------------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name                       | Value    |
+-------------------------------------+----------+
| connect_timeout                     | 10       |
| delayed_insert_timeout              | 300      |
| have_statement_timeout              | YES      |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout         | 1        |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout            | 10       |
| innodb_print_lock_wait_timeout_info | OFF      |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout          | ON       |
| interactive_timeout                 | 600      |
| lock_wait_timeout                   | 3600     |
| mysqlx_connect_timeout              | 30       |
| mysqlx_idle_worker_thread_timeout   | 60       |
| mysqlx_interactive_timeout          | 28800    |
| mysqlx_port_open_timeout            | 0        |
| mysqlx_read_timeout                 | 30       |
| mysqlx_wait_timeout                 | 28800    |
| mysqlx_write_timeout                | 60       |
| net_read_timeout                    | 30       |
| net_write_timeout                   | 60       |
| rpl_stop_slave_timeout              | 31536000 |
| slave_net_timeout                   | 60       |
| thread_pool_idle_timeout            | 60       |
| wait_timeout                        | 600      |
+-------------------------------------+----------+
```

The above is my related question. Currently, the exception occurs once in an unpredictable manner. The program runs a batch task to query the database every morning. The QPS of the database is around 2000, and the batch SQL queries are all simple without any write operations. Also, the queries involve join operations, but they use indexes, and the join is performed with only one table. Could you please help me determine if the issue lies in my configuration or my SQL queries? Thank you.

I tried modifying the configuration of HikariCP, including keepalive-time, max-lifetime, and idle-timeout, but the exception still occurs.

Comment: I guess mysql is running in a different container as your application?

Comment: Change the `minimum-idle` to be lower then the `maximum-pool-size` that way connections will be refreshed periodically when needed. When they are equal this doesn't happen.

Comment: @Jens Yes, MySQL is a master-slave high availability service.I am connecting to the slave database.

Comment: @M.Deinum I apologize for the confusion. Let me clarify.

Regarding your question, would modifying the "minimum-idle" and "maximum-pool-size" settings help resolve my issue?

Comment: It will keep dynamically growing the pool, if needed and scale down. It will automatically close idle connections after the idle timeout. But it does this only when the min/max are different else it doesn't do this until an error pops up. Will it solve it, not sure but it will help. If you still have long running queries that keep a connection busy it still might occur. You might want to set the `spring.datasource.hikari.leak-detection-threshold` to some value, this wil report connection leaks and help investigation.

Comment: @M.Deinum Sure, I will test it following your instructions, and I will provide a response once I have the results.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thank you all for your responses. After several days of testing and troubleshooting based on the exception stack information, we have finally identified the root cause of the issue. By modifying relevant configuration settings, we have successfully resolved the problem and the similar exceptions are no longer occurring. Here's the explanation:

As described in the original exception stack information, the `Read timed out` exception was occurring. The code that was throwing this exception is located in the `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.isReadOnly` method. Here is the code snippet:

```
public boolean isReadOnly(boolean useSessionStatus) throws SQLException {
        if (useSessionStatus && !this.session.isClosed() && versionMeetsMinimum(5, 6, 5) && !this.useLocalSessionState.getValue()
                && this.readOnlyPropagatesToServer.getValue()) {
            String s = this.session.queryServerVariable(
                    versionMeetsMinimum(8, 0, 3) || (versionMeetsMinimum(5, 7, 20) && !versionMeetsMinimum(8, 0, 0)) ? "@@session.transaction_read_only"
                            : "@@session.tx_read_only");
            if (s != null) {
                return Integer.parseInt(s) != 0; // mysql has a habit of tri+ state booleans
            }
        }

        return this.readOnly;
    }
```

The logic of this code snippet involves determining whether to set the session as read-only based on the MySQL version. This involves executing a large number of select @@session.tx_read_only statements to ensure the consistency of the current session.

Solution: Since our service is designed as a read-only project and does not require consistency checks or data submission, we have made the following changes to the MySQL database connection configuration:
Added `useLocalSessionState=true` in the connection information.

Removed the `auto-commit: true` configuration.
With the above modifications, our service has now returned to normal operation.